# Broadcast receiver inside a Service doesn't work

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver inside a Service. The service should start an alarm manager and the broadcast receiver should receive the alarm. The service is started by a another broadcast receiver after device restart. but my code gives following exception and app crashes. How can I fix this?

```
06-28 17:26:20.983 6924-6924/com.example.krishan.timertest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.krishan.timertest, PID: 6924
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.krishan.timertest.MyService$AlarmReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.example.krishan.timertest.MyService$AlarmReceiver has no zero argument constructor
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2992)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:177)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
   Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.example.krishan.timertest.MyService$AlarmReceiver has no zero argument constructor
      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1681)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2987)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:177) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) 
   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
      at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:510)
      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1679)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2987) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:177) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

**My service**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.d("timer test", "*********************" + " Service Started " + "*********************");
        startAlert();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void startAlert() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), (60 * 1000), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in 60 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("Timer Test", "*********************" + " Alarm" + "*********************");
        }
    }
}
```

**My broadcast receiver triggered when boot completed**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Intent ServiceIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(ServiceIntent);


        Toast.makeText(context, "Boot Receiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intentx = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intentx.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intentx);

    }

}
```

**My Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.krishan.timertest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".MyService$AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This works properly if I declared the broadcast receiver as a separate class. But I want to declare it inside the service.

Comment: please check weather your service is getting started or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AlarmReceiver class should be static,
hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar,register the batteryBroadcast and the ScreenOn/ScreenOf Broadcast too, check the code:

```
public class turnOnScreenService extends Service {



    private BroadcastReceiver mScreenStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String strAction = intent.getAction();

            if (strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                //do stuff
            } else if (strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                //do more stuff
            }
        }
    };

    private BroadcastReceiver mBatteryStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
               // more stuff

            } else {
               // more stuff
            }
        }
    };


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
        screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        registerReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver, screenStateFilter);


        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter();
        ifilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
        ifilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
        registerReceiver(mBatteryStateReceiver, ifilter);
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(mBatteryStateReceiver);
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the action which I should use here with `intentFilter.addAction()`

Comment: Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED
Please, upvote the answer

Comment: There is no problem with the Boot receiving broadcast receiver. Making the inner class inside the service made my problem solved.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to up vote answers. reputation must be greater than 10 for that